# Taylor expansion for left&right limit

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I must find the left and the right limits of a function.
Can I use the Taylor expansion (at $x_0$) in order to evaluate them?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. The Taylor expansion may not exist at $x_0$. For example, using the Heaviside theta function $\Theta(x)$ and $x_0=0$, one obtains
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\Theta(x)=1\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}\Theta(x)=0$$
whereas the Taylor expansion of $\Theta$ at $0$ does not exist.

Comment: Wow! But does it work with the function, for example, $\frac{1}{xln2}-\frac{5}{6^x+7}$?

Comment: @HakoonaMatata: Note that since a Taylor polynomial is continuous and differentiable at its expansion point, the left and right limits of the Taylor expansion are the same, and equal to $f(x_0)$; therefore, for any function whose left and right limits at $x_0$ are different, the Taylor expansion method can't work. For $f(x)=\frac{1}{xln2}-\frac{5}{6^x+7}$, if $x_0\neq 0$ then the Taylor series should converge, and you'll get the right answer. At $x_0=0$ the function has a singularity, and the Taylor series will not converge properly, so you'll have to evaluate the left/right limits manually.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now, how can I evaluate left&right limit of $\frac{1}{xln2}-\frac{1}{2^x-1}$?? Both must return $\frac{1}{2}$